# Problem with Gnome3 on Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome, startup

I recently installed the gnome3 on my Ubuntu some 1-2 months ago, it was working nice, but today, i was trying a theme, and then after reverting, the gnome-shell is not working!, When i select gnome, it runs the ubuntu-2d or  something mixed, there are no animations, but it is not ubuntu-2d,whatever it is... is no gnome!

> Reinstalled gnome-shell, gnome-core, gnome-session!
>   Now the "gnome" is not installing, it says that i do not have gnome-core installed, or when clicked "Install", It does nothing, but within half a second, switches between Installing.. and then back to "Free" .

**What should i do?**

Answer (score 1):

Revise your software sources, make sure you have only oficial sources activated. Deactivate any "test" sources.

Then do `apt-get remove--purge gnome-shell` and install it again.

Also, make sure your display driver is installed and working properly, for the 3d to work, or else, gnome will log you into gnome-classic